# Absolute Positioning of button inside textarea

Tags: html, css

[image: snnipet]

The gear button in the above picture is positioned absolute inside the textarea element, but the text is getting overlapped with it. I don't want to apply padding-right property.
I am new with HTML and CSS. How to stop text getting collapsed with gear button.

Comment: post a jsfiddle or something to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really can get away from `padding` as this is the right thing to do in your case.
(else please state why don't you want to use `padding`?)

Check this code out, maybe you'll find it more elegant to use the icon as a `background-image`.
You could play with the `width`, `height`, and `padding-right` values:

HTML part:

`<textarea>hello hksjf askdjfj akldfla </textarea>`

CSS Part:

```
textarea {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-image: url('http://www.isilo.com/support/manual/iSiloIP/img/gearIcon.gif');
    background-position: top right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Also in jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nQkEG/

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UNz8a/2/) using another approach.

I have created a wrapper element with relative positioning, gave border to it and set its width to 300px. Then created a textarea element without any border and set its width to 280px in order to position your gear (positioned absolutely, `float:right`) at the top-right corner, so the text won't overlap you button.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <textarea class='textarea'></textarea>  
    <img src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/unicons-vector-icons-pack/32/settings-128.png' class='img'>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;  

}

.textarea{
    position:relative;
    width:280px;
    height:100px;
    border:0px solid;
    resize:none

}

.img{
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't. 
Either use `padding-right` on the `textarea` or `float` the button to the `right`.

Comment: using padding-right (or padding-top) may be acceptable but I couldn't imagine how a button floats to the right of a **textarea**?